# Salesforce Login

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

I am using zksforce SDK from [here](https://github.com/palaniraja/Force.com-Toolkit-for-iOS/tree/master/SVNTest). 
Every time when i starts my application it shows me login form. Instead of this I just want to maintain log in session till the user logs out. 
Is it possible? What should I do for this? Following is my code that shows the log in form for salesforce.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    sectionViewController = [[SFT1SectionViewController alloc] init];
    oAuthViewController = [[FDCOAuthViewController alloc] initWithTarget:sectionViewController selector:@selector(loginOAuth:error:) clientId:kSFOAuthConsumerKey];
    oAuthViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
    self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:oAuthViewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

I also tried for custom login using loginWithUsername:password: method but it gives me token error saying that i should attach security token along with the password. what does that mean? I am calling method using following line :

```
[[FDCServerSwitchboard switchboard] loginWithUsername:usernameTextField.text password:passwordTextField.text target:rootViewController selector:@selector(loginResult:error:)];
```

This problem can also be solved by saving password when user logs in using web view. Is it possible to save password like this? If yes, how?

Comment: I dont see any objective-c++ code. retagged.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might be missing the security token. It's appended to the end of the password.

This link explains how to generate the token

https://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/user_security_token.htm

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *password = @"Your password here";
NSString *token = @"your token here";
NSString *passwordToken = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", password, token];
[[FDCServerSwitchboard switchboard] loginWithUsername:username password:passwordToken target:self selector:@selector(loginResult:error:)];
```

This would do. If you have forgot your token you can reset and the token will be sent to your email. You can do this through setup -> personal information -> reset token.